# Client side programming languages in web development

Tags: javascript, client-side

Are there client side programming languages other than JavaScript in web development?

Comment: Yes. Actionscript in Flash, C# in Silverlight, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBScript, but it's IE only.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z7ye5ke(v=vs.85).aspx